# Google Search Console api won't let me query my own domain

Tags: search, console, google-apis-explorer

I own a domain and it's enabled on Search Console.

When trying to query it from

https://developers.google.com/webmaster-tools/search-console-api-original/v3/searchanalytics/query

I have the following error

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "forbidden",
    "message": "User does not have sufficient permission for site 'http://example.net/'. See also: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2451999."
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "User does not have sufficient permission for site 'http://example.net/'. See also: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2451999."
 }
}
```

I auth with the same account that owns the domain, of course.

ALSO

I have an older domain on the same account and if I query its root, it works. But if I try any other page in that domain, for instance http://www.example2.net/page, it returns the same error.

Am I missing something?

Comment: have you managed to get around this?